# Learning to write an article with Xepersian from a to z

Tags: xepersian

I have to make a Latex file out of my article in three days and my article is in Farsi.I downloaded Miktex,winedt10,Texlive...
but I don`t know how to use the xepersian packages and I need to learn how to write that fom a to z.
so any hope that I can find a source for that?

Comment: You can subscribe to official Persian TeX mailing list on TUG (TeX Users Group) at:

tug.org/mailman/listinfo/persiantex

Answer (score 2):

Here are some templates. Try to adapt these files to your needs :

[From overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/farsi#.W3Cj2zPfs0M)

[From another site](https://taeri.iut.ac.ir/some-sample-xepersian-files)

[Another one](https://github.com/nkhdiscovery/XePersian-Samples)

Comment: You can subscribe to official Persian TeX mailing list on TUG (TeX Users Group) at:

tug.org/mailman/listinfo/persiantex